# Using a list to name output files in Arcpy

Tags: python, extract, arcpy, arcmap

I am working with NLCD data set and am trying to extract changed pixels based on county boundaries (extract by mask). I have wrote a little script that will do the job BUT i was wondering if somehow I could use the boundary names as my output names because at the moment, the output is just `1, 2, 3, ...`
As you will see, I am using a counter. I tried `counter = ctyList` but it doesn't work. 
Here is the script:

```
import os
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
env.workspace = "C:\Users\sr\Desktop\Sam\AllCounties"
ctyList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses ("*.shp")
inRaster = "nlcdrecmosaic"
counter = 1
for shp in ctyList:
 out= arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(inRaster,shp)
 out.save("C:\Users\sr\Desktop\Sam\AllCounties\out\mskd"+ str(counter))
 counter = counter + 1
```

Thank you very much for your help.
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for shp in ctyList:
    county_name = shp.split('.')[0]  # Split the file name at the '.' to get just the name without the extension 
    out= arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(inRaster,shp)
    out.save("C:\Users\sr\Desktop\Sam\AllCounties\out\mskd"+ county_name
```

Comment: I am sorry if this question is a bit stupid, but for 'file_name_list' Do I just do as you have done  or have to input the names of the counties? I don't quite understand the "name1, name2" I am very new to python so excuse my question.

Comment: You should actually just be able to use the feature class names in `ctyList`. I'll update my answer

Comment: thank you so much for your help. It seems to work. Just a question, I was wondering what is that [0] at the end of the split? Is it saying that do not keep anything after '.'?

Comment: Basically, yes. The `split` function splits a string at a specified character and then puts the resulting sub-strings into a list. So for the string 'countyname.shp' the above split would result in the list `['countyname', 'shp']`. The [0] is taking the element of the list at index 0, in this case, the string 'countyname'.